# AWS codebuild gradle task failed to download from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

My aws Codebuild task failed due to not able to download from S3 bucket with following error message.

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; 
Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: ***; S3 Extended Request ID: *** )
```

I already attache policy to this role

```
{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
      ],
      "Resource": "ARN: arn:aws:s3:::***",
    }
```

What did i miss here ?

Comment: It clearly says: double check the secrets provided to that task. Probably an extra space at the end or so.